# source of ping in kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, ping

I am learning about raw sockets. I heard that ping utility is using raw sockets. So I want to study it source. So can somebody help me to find where is the source code of ping utility in the linux-2.6 kernel code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not part of the kernel.  It's part of the [iputils package](http://www.skbuff.net/iputils/).

Answer (score 1):

Its not in kernel. ping is part of "iputils". find an iputils source package and look from there.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, it's included in `iputils`, but also `inetutils`. Therefore you can run either of the following (assuming Debian/Ubuntu Linux) to view the source:

`apt-get source iputils`

`apt-get source inetutils`